# I am trying to import a class from one file to another module in Visual Studios (Python) and its not working

Tags: python

Here is my class code that I am trying to import, the file is called car.py:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()
    def read_odometer(self):
        print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")
    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't rollback the odometer.")
    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        self.odometer_reading += miles\\\
```

Thats my class and here is the code I am trying to use to import it in Visual Studios in another file but its not working:

```
import sys
from car.py import Car
my_new_car = Car("audi", "a4", 2019)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
my_new_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_new_car.read_odometer()
```

Comment: `from car import Car`, in python you do not have to mention the `.py` extension. Also the file should be in the same directory as that of the file which you will be executing...

Comment: i tried that and it says unresolved import 'car', they are in the same directory

Comment: nevermind i figured it out...thanks for the help

Comment: @illusion " Also the file should be in the same directory as that of the file which you will be executing..." That is not a requirement

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga otherwise, you need to specify it via the relative path. Like if its in a directory, then " import directory.car", right?

Comment: @illusion fundamentally it needs to be in the [import path](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-import-path). The current working directory when you run the python interpreter is automatically added to the import path.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! something new to me...!